# How to solve an integral equation by iteration method?

Tags: recursion, integral-equations

How I can obtain $n^{th}$ approximation of the following equation
$f(t)=t+\int_0^tds f(s)$
 by iteration method?

Comment: I've rolled back your question to it's original version, as I think your change of dimension is significant enough to warrant a new question.  Feel free to open such a new question! Furthermore, no one can really answer this one, as it's closed anyway! (Not that I agree with the closure.)

Comment: Please don't roll back my roll back! Honestly, it makes no sense for two reasons. Your original question refers to quite a specific operator so changing the operator wastes the efforts of those who answered the question. Secondly, this question has been closed so no one can answer it now anyway. If you have another question, simply open a new question.

Comment: @Javad I encourage you to post a new question as Mark suggested.

Comment: I am so sorry @MarkMcClure. I am a beginner in this area.

Comment: No biggie - you'll probably be an expert one day!

Answer (score 3):

```
T[f_] := t + Integrate[f /. t -> s, {s, 0, t}];
NestList[T, t, 5]

(* Out: 
  {t, t + t^2/2, t + t^2/2 + t^3/6, 
   t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + t^4/24, 
   t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + t^4/24 + t^5/120, 
   t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + t^4/24 + t^5/120 + t^6/720}
*)
```

Looks like $f(t)=e^t - 1$ is a fixed point.

```
T[E^t - 1]
(* Out: -1 + E^t *)
```

Comment: what is your opinion about matrix form of the equation? for example $F(t)=A(t)+\int_0^tB(s)F(s)ds$ where F, A and B are matrices.

Comment: @JavadKazemi I think the same basic idea should work, though it would be nice to have a specific example in mind.

Comment: What is your idea about $A(t)=\bigg{(}\begin{matrix}
   t & 0 \\
   Cos(t) & 1  \end{matrix}\bigg{)}$ and $B(s)=\bigg{(}\begin{matrix}
   e^s & 0 \\
   0 & e^{-s}  \end{matrix}\bigg{)}$?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wanted the Neumann series method.

```
ClearAll[f, t, s];
f[0] = t;
f[n_] := f[n] = Integrate[(f[n - 1] /. t -> s) s, {s, 0, t}];
data = Table[f[i], {i, 0, 10}]
Total@data
% /. t -> .5
(*0.543827*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I win - by 10 seconds! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have hidden functions and variables:

```
n = 4; (*Put whatever term you want here*)
x0 = 0; (*This is the point you want to expand around*)
(*Define g[s] here*)
g[t] = t + Integrate[f[s], {s, 0, t}] ;
Series[g[t], {t, x0, n}];
Normal[%][[n]] (*This is the answer you want*)
```