# Recursive Function Numerical Integration

Tags: numerical-integration, recursion, integral-equations

I just tried to modify a code snippet for Neumann series to the Fredholm integral equation

$ f(x)= \sqrt{x} - \int^1_0 dy\; f(y) \sqrt{x y} $

which I read in another post: [How to solve an integral equation by iteration method?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55600/how-to-solve-an-integral-equation-by-iteration-method) with a slightly different integral, namely :

```
f[0]:=Sqrt[x];
f[n_]:=Sqrt[x]-Integrate[(f[n-1]/.x->y)*Sqrt[x*y],{y,0,1}];
data=Table[f[i],{i,0,10}];
```

The code works well but for my later application I need to solve those types of integrals numerically because the Kernel is too complicated to be solved by Integrate[]. Therefore I want to replace the integration by a numerical integration in the above code and naively tried

```
h[x_,0]:=Sqrt[x];
h[x_,n_]:=InterpolatingPolynomial[
Table[{x,Sqrt[x]-NIntegrate[h[y,n-1]*Sqrt[x*y],{y,0,1},AccuracyGoal->4]},{x,0,1,.1}], x];
data2=Table[h[x,i],{i,0,3}];
```

However even for a short series up to 3 iterations the computing time "explodes" and already exceeds the first code. How can I improve the code / computation?

I tried to replace the InterpolatingPolynomial by Interpolation[]

```
h[x_, 0] := Sqrt[x];
hint := Interpolation[Table[{x,Sqrt[x]-NIntegrate[h[y,n-1]*Sqrt[x*y],{y,0,1},AccuracyGoal->4]},{x,0,1,.1}]];
h[x_, n_] := hint[x];
data = Table[h[x, i], {i, 0, 3}];
```

but that code does not even compute the first iteration step h[x,1]

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to post your actual function and see if anyone can find a fast method for integrating.

Comment: @JackLaVigne my kernel is a rather complicated function of temperature derivatives of bose distributions and a scattering matrix and has no easy analytical solution. I think as soon as I understand how to numerically calculate the Neumann series for an easy integral like this one here with a numerical integration I can apply it to my actual problem.

Comment: Memoization helps a bit with the speed at the expense of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the expense of memory you can get some increase in speed by using [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica).

Here is the timing using the original defintion:

```
h[x_, 0] := Sqrt[x]

h[x_, n_] := 
 InterpolatingPolynomial[
  Table[{x, Sqrt[x] - 
     NIntegrate[h[y, n - 1]*Sqrt[x*y], {y, 0, 1}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 4]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}], x]
```

Now

```
AbsoluteTiming[data = Table[h[x, i], {i, 0, 3}];]

(* {5.54783, Null} *)
```

Memorize each step as you compute

```
hr[x_, 0] = Sqrt[x]

hr[x_, n_] := 
 hr[x, n] = 
  InterpolatingPolynomial[
   Table[{x, Sqrt[x] - 
      NIntegrate[hr[y, n - 1]*Sqrt[x*y], {y, 0, 1}, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 4]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}], x]
```

The timing is much better

```
AbsoluteTiming[data = Table[hr[x, i], {i, 0, 3}];]

(* {0.293722, Null} *)
```

After clearing everything here is the time to compute the table with `i` set to 10.

```
AbsoluteTiming[data = Table[hr[x, i], {i, 0, 10}];]

(* {1.35537, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem!